# Flutter, Bloc. What is the difference between operator== and const?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Why add `operator==` or some helper packages to states/events during comparison when you can just add `const` to the constructor?

```
abstract class PersonBase {
  const PersonBase();
}

class Person extends PersonBase {
  const Person({required this.name});

  final String name;
}
```

```
abstract class PersonBase {}

class Person extends PersonBase {
  Person({required this.name});

  final String name;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  
    return other is Person &&
      other.name == name;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual use of the const keyword is to serve as an indicator that tells the compiler that, for this variable, it will never change in the lifetime of this code, so create just one copy of it and where ever it is mentioned, just reference back to the one copy you already created and don’t create a new one.

Dart reuse the same reference of variable mentioned as `const` if already referenced in the same way. This will work like `Literal Pool` in java.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, The `const` keyword is used to specify that the `Person` class is immutable and may be constructed at compile-time, the `operator==` method is used in the code sample you supplied to compare Person instances for equality.